# Why redirect uri not working?

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, uri

I have a problem with my fb app, I have set the path as `mySite.com/facebook/appName` there are all php files and set it to login with facebook, but when I enter the field path `mySite.com/facebook/appName/` it returns 191 error! It used to work fine last week! I've tried everything  `mySite.com/facebook/` and `mySite.com/` but still nothing!

Comment: There were some breaking changes recently. Do you have the latest version of the php sdk https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: ok i will try get the latest thanks maybe that is thanks a lot my friend i will test it!

Comment: no i changed nothing happen same problem! thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API 191 error is raised when the `redirect_uri` is not relative or equivalent to the site's path.

For example, if your site is set to `mySite.com/myhomepage` and your `redirect_uri` is set to `mySite.com/facebook/appName` you would have issues.

The `redirect_uri` MUST be relative to the site path. That means that they domains must match, and the path of your `redirect_uri` must contain any path components of your site's URL.

If you could post a screenshot of your FB app's configuration, we may be able to help. Howerver, this is not a PHP question, nor a programming question at all.

Comment: How must set the redirect uri in app when i have the path set as "mySite.com/facebook/myappName/" ?

Comment: my site path is "mySite.com/siteName/index.html" and the application set as mySite.com/siteName/facebook/myappName/example.php what redirect uri i must set?

Comment: Still have problems no-one knows?

Comment: Remove the /index.html from your site path.

Comment: nothing happen i just want found what url i will add in login with facebook iput field in my app!